# Specify ruby version to use with Pik

Tags: ruby, windows

I need to run two Ruby apps on a Windows 2008 server. So, I'm thinking to install **Pik** for the job (I understand I could use also RVM but the install process doesn't seem very 'stable' to me).

Before installing Pik, however, I'd like to know if there is a way to specify which Ruby version should be used for each app. Something like a .ruby-version file. I have looked for the answer on the official Pik repo but I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, [Ref 1](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2010/08/installing-rails-30-ruby-192-and-pik-on/), [Ref 2](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/03/10/using-pik-to-manage-multiple-versions-of-ruby-on-windows/) are the two simple references you could have to install different ruby versions using Pik in Windows.

After setting up the environment correctly, you could just use the command similar to RVM.

```
pik use ruby-2.0.0-p0
```

Then `ruby -v` will show `ruby 2.0.0p0`. So, for different projects, from with in each project folder choose which ruby you want to have.

Hope it helps :)